# How to select a record from duplicate records based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table X which has three columns SN , OI, FLAG .
Some sample values are

```
SN OI FLAG
1   a  Y
1   a  N
2   x  N
3   d  N
3   d  Null
4   z  Y
4   z  null
5   k  Y
5   k  Y
5   k  Y
6   l  N
6   l  N
```

I want the result on the below condition 
If there are multiple values of same SN , i want the result on the condition that if FLAG has Y and N , then it should show Y , IF Flag has Null and N , it should show N , IF Flag has Y and Null, then is should show Y. SO in the above example this is what I should get .

```
SN FLAG
 1 Y
 2 N
 3 N
 4 Y 
 5 Y 
 6 N
```

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to provide additional information of clarification. In particular code and sample data examples are hard to read in comments due to poor layout and lack of formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group by sn` and get the flag with conditional aggregation:

```
select sn,
  case
    when sum(case flag when 'Y' then 1 end) > 0 then 'Y'
    when sum(case flag when 'N' then 1 end) > 0 then 'N'
  end flag
from tablename
group by sn
order by sn
```

In your special case, this should also work:

```
select sn, max(flag) flag
from tablename
group by sn
order by sn
```

because 'Y' > 'N'.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8572a682e72ea5396d05356b07627cb4).
Results:

```
> SN | FLAG
> -: | :---
>  1 | Y   
>  2 | N   
>  3 | N   
>  4 | Y   
>  5 | Y   
>  6 | N
```

Comment: what if the flag values is NULL NULL .then what will it take?

Comment: The result will be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

For your given rules, you can just use `MAX()`:

```
select sn, max(flag) as flag
from t
group by sn;
```